# How to fix this code on angular httpclient with delete method

Tags: angular, httpclient, http-delete

(english is not my first language so please forgive me)
Hey i'm new at Angular and i'm trying do a http request that delete a doctor when i click on a button (for example), and know im struggling on what i have to do to make my code working. thank you

here's doctor.service.ts

```js
getDoctor(doctorId: string): Observable<Doctor> {
    return this.http.get<Doctor>(`${this.apiUrl}/${doctorId}`, {headers})
        .pipe(map((doctor: Doctor) => {
            return doctor;
        }), catchError((error: any) => {
            this.getError(error);
            return of<Doctor>(EMPTY_DOCTOR);
        }));
}

deleteDoctor(DoctorId: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/${DoctorId}`, {headers})
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with your code? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Check the tutorial, it's pretty clear https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#delete-a-hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your `deleteDoctor()` method you should probably call the subscribe method of your observable:

```js
deleteDoctor(DoctorId: string): Observable<void> {
    this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/${DoctorId}`, {headers})
        .subscribe(response => {
            // Do something here if needed...
        });
}
```

You can also keep your method and call it this way:

```js
this.deleteDoctor().subscribe(response => {
    // Do something here if needed...
});
```